# How to substitute the remote_function to some jquery call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, prototype, redmine

I'm doing a migration of code in Redmine and the actual version doesn't accepts the `remote_function` call.

So I read that has one way to do the same thing that `remote_function` did before using `jquery`. The problem is I have no idea of how to do it. Someone can help me?

Bellow my code:

view.rb

```
<%= button_to_function l(:gerar_build_project), remote_function(:action => 'exec_client', :controller => 'repositories') %>
```

repositories_controller.rb

```
 def exec_client
     ...
 end
```

routes.rb

```
match 'projects/:id/repository', :action => 'exec_client', :controller => 'repositories', :via => :post
match 'projects/:id/repository/:branch', :action => 'exec_client', :controller => 'repositories', :via => :post
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to write an AJAX query by hand or something else? That's essentially what `remote: true` and the UJS driver do. https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
<%= button_to l(:gerar_build_project),
      {:action => 'exec_client', :controller => 'repositories'},
      {:remote => true, :method => :post} %>
```